# Marlin v. Repetier G-code flavor

Tags: marlin, firmware, repetier

My TronXY X1 runs on Repetier firmware. My Ender 3 runs on Marlin firmware.

I found that apparently code in Marlin style does not always create good prints on a Repetier machine, under extruding in some key areas - but that might also be setting dependant.

Of course, simple fix in the slicer by setting it to the correct style, but:

**What differences are in the style of the basic commands between Marlin and Repetier?**

Comment: Does code in Repetier style produce good prints on Marlin firmware? If so then it might just be Repeiter has a bad g-code interpreter, which the slicer software is compensating for.

Comment: @user77232 actually some file work either way, but I have an old g-code file that works perfectly, and a new one where I tried Marlin Style that fails constantly - so I wondered if it was G-code style error.

Comment: The basics should be the same, are you sure about settings like steps per mm for both machines ( I'm not referring that they need to be the same value). There are a lot of other G-codes that are different, supported by one but not the other, etc., but these are not the standard ones.

Comment: @0scar I am sure that the machine settings are working - but it might very well be slicer settings totally off...